# WPF popup not getting minimized when click on the taskbar application icon

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit, wpf-4.0

Below is my code.

```
popupTargetPlacementWindow.LocationChanged += delegate(object obj, EventArgs args)
                {
                    if (ErrorPopUp.IsOpen == true)
                    {
                        ErrorPopUp.IsOpen = false;
                        ErrorPopUp.IsOpen = true;                        
                    }
                };
                popupTargetPlacementWindow.Deactivated += delegate(object obj, EventArgs args)
                {                    
                    ErrorPopUp.IsOpen = false;                    
                };
                popupTargetPlacementWindow.Activated += delegate(object obj, EventArgs args)
                {                    
                    ErrorPopUp.IsOpen = true;                    
                };
```

The problem with this code is when i use minimize button to minimize the application it works fine(wpf popup control doesn't display) but when i click on taskbar application icon to minimize the application it gives issue(wpf popup control still display in the upper left corner of the desktop window). i am using the `Window.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanMinimize` flag for our application.

The issue which i found is Activated event is getting fired when clicking on the taskbar application icon hence setting the  ErrorPopUp.IsOpen = true; hence wpf popup is not disappearing while clicking on minimize button doesn't fire the Activated event hence disappearing the wpf popup.

Any help in this regard, how to make this code working so that clicking on taskbar app icon also disappear the wpf popup would be very helpful..

Below is my wpf popup control code.

```
<Image Name="IconInfoTooltip" Source="{Binding TooltipImageSource}" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="575,70,25,325" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0.7" /Image> 
<Popup Name="ErrorPopUp" IsOpen="{Binding IsErrorPopUpOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Width="320" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalOffset="-280" VerticalOffset="-2" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=IconInfoTooltip}" Placement="Top">
<Grid x:Name="grid" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Background="Transparent">
<Border BorderBrush="#ffc64a" BorderThickness="1" Background="LightYellow" CornerRadius="5" Padding="5">
<StackPanel>
<StackPanel>
<BulletDecorator>
<BulletDecorator.Bullet>
<Ellipse Height="6" Width="6" Fill="Black"/>
</BulletDecorator.Bullet>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Message3}" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
</BulletDecorator>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel>
<BulletDecorator>
<BulletDecorator.Bullet>
<Ellipse Height="6" Width="6" Fill="Black"/>
</BulletDecorator.Bullet>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Message2}" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
</BulletDecorator>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel>
<BulletDecorator>
<BulletDecorator.Bullet>
<Ellipse Height="6" Width="6" Fill="Black"/>
</BulletDecorator.Bullet>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Message1}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
</BulletDecorator>
</StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Comment: you could perhaps check the window state in activated event handler

Comment: What sort of window is your pop-up? (ie what sort or WindowStyle does it have?) And can you explain why the above code is necessary? Does it not minimize at all if the above code is removed?

Comment: Pushpraj: I have tried this by adding this line of code Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized in Activated event handler.

David: Have added my wpf popup control code above.
If we removed the above code it will not minimize the wpf popup control.